# It is possible to compute recursive ackermann(m,n) function with args m>=4 and n>=1 in python without exceeding max recursion depth?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, ackermann

It is possible to compute total computable recursive function `ackermann(m,n)` with arguments `m>=4` and `n>=1` in python without exceeding max recursion depth?

```
def ackermann(m,n):

    if m == 0:
        return n+1
    if n == 0:
        return ackermann(m-1,1)
    else:
        return ackermann(m-1,ackermann(m,n-1))

ackermann(4,1)
```

Comment: You know that the ackerman was intentionally defined to show something that increases that largely that it could not be defined by primitive recursive functions?

Comment: Python is not good for recursion. There is no tail-call elimination, and thus, it is always prone to stack-overflow. You can increase the max-recursion depth, but that's there to *prevent* the stack-overflow...

Comment: *ackermann(4, 2)* has almost twenty-thousand decimal digits - and so has the nesting depth taking the (above) definition literally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this level of response, use dynamic programming: *memoize* the function.  This means that you keep a table of previous results.  If you find a result that's already been computed, then you return it from the table.  Only when it's a new call, do you do the computation -- and in that case, most or all of the recursive calls will be in the table.  For instance:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(30000)

memo = {}

def ack(m, n):
    if not (m, n) in memo:
        result = (n + 1) if m == 0 else (
            ack(m-1, 1) if n == 0 else ack(m-1, ack(m, n-1)))
        memo[(m, n)] = result
    return memo[(m, n)]

print ack(3, 4)
print ack(4, 1)
print ack(4, 2)
```

You'll still have trouble with anything as large as **ack(4, 2)**, due to memory use.

```
125
65533
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: How much memory do you have? ack(4, 1) causes a kernel restart in ipython for me.

Comment: The memory is pretty big (but I'm not disclosing); I do some deep learning work on this box.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. One can use `sys.setrecursionlimit` and more mathematics to improve the algorithm. See The [Rosetta Code task](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Python) for Python code.

**Note!**

I just re-ran ack2:

```
%timeit a2 = ack2(4,2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 214 µs per loop

len(str(a2))
Out[9]: 19729
```

That is nearly twenty *thousand* digits in the answer.

Comment: Note that there are *two* versions of **ack2** on the Rosetta page.  My answer is derived from the first; I believe you ran the second, "From the Mathematica ack3 example."  I tried that one, and it has no trouble with ack(4,2).  However, ack(5, 1) still gets a stack overflow, and ack(4, 3) runs a loooong time (as expected).  I killed the job after 15 minutes.